# C++ Tennis Score Tracker

Tags: c++

Taking an intro to C++ class in University and we got this project to 'model' a tennis game.

The user will first need to enter the probability that player a will win. 
Then generate a number between 1 and 100 until a player has more than 4 points and has 2 more points than the other player.

My problem is that sometimes around the 50% win rate area the output will come out as 4-4.

I am wondering why this is happening?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    int prob; 
    int scoreA = 0; 
    int scoreB = 0; 
    int randNB = 0; 

srand(time(NULL)); 

cout <<"---------------\n"
        "FAKE TENNIS!\n"
        "---------------" <<endl;
cout <<"What is the chance that player \'A\' will win a point?(Enter whole #between 1 - 100): " ;
    cin >> prob;
do{
if((scoreA >= 4 || scoreB >= 4) && ((scoreA - scoreB) >= 2 || (scoreB - scoreA) >= 2)) break; 
randNB = rand()%100+1;

    if (randNB <= prob){
        cout<<"A";
        scoreA++;
    }
    else if(randNB > prob){
        cout<<"B";
        scoreB++;
    }


}        
while((scoreA <= 3|| scoreB <= 3) && ((scoreA - scoreB) !=2 || (scoreB - scoreA) !=2 ));

cout<<"The final score is " <<scoreA <<" (A) - " << scoreB <<" (B)" <<endl;
if(scoreA > scoreB){
    cout <<"A is the winner!!!";
}
else{
    cout <<"B is the winner!!!";
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written the end-loop test twice.

Once as a positive inside the loop (correctly) and once as a negative at the end of the loop.

1) Write it only once. (The "break" will end the loop.) That is, replace the do { ... } while(...) with just while(true) { ... }

2) If you want to write it twice, check `<2` rather than `!= 2` in the second test. The negation of x>=2 is not x!=2

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem~